# How to get entire output by using only regular expressions methods in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
>import re

int_br="""
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES NVRAM  up                        
Vlan2                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan3                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan4                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan5                  unassigned      YES unset  down                        
Vlan6                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan7                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan8                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan9                  unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan10                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan11                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan12                 unassigned      YES unset  down                        
Vlan13                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan14                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan15                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan16                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan17                 unassigned      YES unset  up                        
Vlan18                 unassigned      YES unset  down"""
>a=list(int_br.split('\n'))
>i=1
>for l in a:
    if (re.search(r'(up|UP)',a[i])):
        print(a[i])
    i=i+1
```

I want every up interface details as output,but I'm getting only top 4 lines.Could anyone tell me the what is the concept behind this output. Is any other way to write this program by using only re methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should do as josifoski wrote as you have made your code complicated by unnecessarily using the variable 'i'.

Anyway, the fault in your code is actually that you have put the statement 
(i = i + 1) inside 'if' block which should be outside 'if' block and inside 'for' block like below because whether or not the line contains (up|UP), 'i' should be increased.

```
for l in a:
    if (re.search(r'(up|UP)',a[i])):
        print(a[i])
    i=i+1
```

Please focus on programming basics. Best of luck!

Comment: can anyone tell me is this the way to write regular expressions scripts,or can we write more efficient script.

Comment: The code by josifoski is enough, I think

Answer (score 0):

Your example slightly modified

```
import re
a=int_br.split('\n')
for l in a:
    if (re.search(r'(up|UP)', l)):
        print(l)
```

Comment: `for l in int_br.splitliines():` would be even better, right?

Comment: less code which may lead to question why python and not awk